# Why address of struct's member in union lay like this?

Tags: c, union

I have basic idea about how address of member in union would be. Recently I found a data structure like following:

```
typedef union {
    char data[16];

    struct {
        uint8_t filler[15],
            /* how many free bytes in this stack allocated string
            * same idea as fbstring
            */
            space_left : 4,
            /* if it is on heap, set to 1 */
            is_ptr : 1, flag1 : 1, flag2 : 1, flag3 : 1;
    };

    /* heap allocated */
    struct {
        char *ptr;
        /* supports strings up to 2^54 - 1 bytes */
        size_t size : 54,
            /* capacity is always a power of 2 (unsigned)-1 */
            capacity : 6;
        /* the last 4 bits are important flags */
    };
} xs;
```

Then I print most member's address like:

```
(gdb) p &string
$1 = (xs *) 0x7fffffffdc20
(gdb) p &string->data
$2 = (char (*)[16]) 0x7fffffffdc20
(gdb) p &string->filler
$3 = (uint8_t (*)[15]) 0x7fffffffdc20
(gdb) p &string->space_left
$4 = (uint8_t *) 0x7fffffffdc2f ""
(gdb) p &string->is_ptr
$5 = (uint8_t *) 0x7fffffffdc2f ""
(gdb) p &string->flag1
$6 = (uint8_t *) 0x7fffffffdc2f ""
(gdb) p &string->ptr
$7 = (char **) 0x7fffffffdc20
(gdb) p &string->size
$8 = (size_t *) 0x7fffffffdc28
(gdb) p &string->capacity
$9 = (size_t *) 0x7fffffffdc28
(gdb) p &string->flag2
$10 = (uint8_t *) 0x7fffffffdc2f ""
(gdb)
```

I can understand why array `data`, `filler` and `ptr` start the same address.

But why `space_left`,`is_ptr` ...  start the same address? Also, why the offset between `space_left` and `filler` is 16 instead of 8*15?

Comment: A union only reserves space for the largest member. It's not a struct, you can't store multiple members at the same time. With a union, the value for union is the last value stored. (though you can access those bytes differently through the different members) So yes, all members of a union share the same starting address -- because there is only one block of storage for the whole thing.

Comment: References: [C11 Standard - 6.5.2.3 Structure and union members](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3) and [6.5.8 Relational operators(p5)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8p5) `"...All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal. ..."`

Comment: Yes, I agree with 'all members of a union share the same starting address', but some member of struct start in different address, why?

Comment: A `struct` is different. A `struct` reserves storage for EACH member separately separated by any number of padding bytes as required (different for each compiler). So you can store each member of a struct at the same time. That is the basic difference between a `struct` and a `union`.

Comment: Also one thing I can't understand is some member in struct start at same address. e.g is_ptr and flag1

Comment: Yes, anything with a `':'` followed by a number is a *bit-field*. It is only one object which is partitioned into so many bits for each. Like `size_t size : 54, capacity : 6;` is just one `size_t` variable, but the first 54-bits are accessible through `size` and the next 6-bits through `capacity`, but it is all the same `size_t` member.

Comment: @Steven: You used bit fields. The whole point of bit fields is that you can pack a number of small values into the space occupied by a larger type. There's no such thing as a bit address, and it's accurately reporting that `space_left` and `is_ptr` are located within the same byte. Similarly, `size` and `capacity` are located within the same `size_t`. It's not relevant that one of them is further along in the `size_t` such that it might have a different byte address; the address is for the `size_t` they've been smuggled inside, and it's the same for both.

Comment: Oh, those variables share same 8 bits type. Thanks your answer.

Comment: Maybe you can post them as answer, I can select you later.

Comment: Think of it this way. You declare 1-union. It will have storage for the largest of `char data[16];` or `struct {uint8_t filler[15], space_left : 4, is_ptr : 1, flag1 : 1, flag2 : 1, flag3 : 1; }` (which is a 15-byte array + 1-byte split into a bit-field) or `struct { char *ptr, size_t size :54, capacity : 6; }` All can fit into 16-bytes -- so that should be the total size of the `union`. `data` and each struct will share the same starting address. Within each struct you will have a separate address for each separate member (other than the first) -- subject to the bit-field discussion above.

Comment: Note that the compiler would not allow you to take the address of a bit-field.  The debugger is doing its best to handle your request, but you shouldn't be doing it.  You have to forgo pointers to values when you use bit-fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether by intent or happy coincidence, you have chosen an example of `union` and `stuct` to learn from that covers most of the features of each -- even if that does make it a bit more complicated to digest all at one time.

**union**

The primary difference between a `union` and `struct` is that a `union` only provides a single block of storage capable of storing the largest of all of its members, and the value of the `union` is that of the last value stored. A `union` can only store the value of one of its members at any given point in time, but the bytes that make up the last value stored may be viewed through any of its members. All members of a `union` share the same starting address. See: [C11 Standard - 6.5.8 Relational operators(p5)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8p5) `"...All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal. ..."`

**struct**

By contrast, a `stuct` provides storage for each of its members and can store each member independent of any other. The size of a `struct` is the sum of the size of each of the members plus any padding bytes necessary to maintain proper alignment of members. (padding bytes may appear between or after any member but not before the first -- the address of a `struct` is the address of its first member) Where padding occurs is not specified by the standard so compilers are free to place padding byte however they choose to implement the struct.

Additionally, both a `union` and `struct` can contain *bit-fields* specified with the `':'` followed by the number of bits to associate with a given field. The bit fields are created from a single member. In your case above the `size_t size : 54, capacity : 6;` creates a bit-field from a single `size_t` member allowing access to the first `54` bits through `size` and the following `6` bits through `capacity`. Both `size` and `capacity` are fields within the same `size_t` member.

**Why Some Members Have the Same Address and Some Don't?**

The easiest way to understand this is to take what you have as an example. You declare 1-`union`. It will have storage for the largest of `char data[16];` or `struct {uint8_t filler[15], space_left : 4, is_ptr : 1, flag1 : 1, flag2 : 1, flag3 : 1; }` (which is a 15-byte array + 1-byte split into a bit-field) or `struct { char *ptr, size_t size :54, capacity : 6; }` All can fit into 16-bytes -- so that should be the total size of the union. `data` and each `struct` will share the same starting address -- that being the address of the `union`. See, e.g. [C11 Standard - 6.5.2.3 Structure and union members](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3)

Within each `struct` you will have a separate address for each separate member (other than the first) -- subject to the bit-field discussion above. Your first `struct` has a `uint8_t filler[15]` array and then a one-byte bit-field `space_left`. The address of `filler` will be the address of the `union`. The address of `uint8_t space_left` will have an address of its own. For your second `struct`, you have a pointer `ptr` and then a `size_t size` also made into a bit-field. `ptr` will have the address of the `union` and `size` will have an addresss of its own.

(as noted by [JohnathanLeffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler), you should not attempt to take the address of the individual bit-fields within any member)

So why do the structs and each of their first members have same address as the `union`? Recall, a `union` is a single block of storage for the largest member. All `union` members will share the same starting address. Also recall that the address of a `struct` is the address of the first member, so each of `struct` and the first members of each struct within the `union` will also share the `union` address as their address. That leaves only additional members of each `struct` having their own address, but as noted in the comment you should not attempt to take the address of the individual bit-fields as they are created from a single struct-member.

Hopefully this has captured the discussion from earlier. Let me know if you have further questions.